# How can i get the name of the interface, its type and ip?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

Can I display ONLY this data about network devices in this order:

device name - type(vlan,bond,etc) - ipaddress

The NetworkManager does something similar with the command :
"nmcli device status"

Comment: Something like `ip -o a s`?

Comment: what about interfaces without type (eg: real interfaces)? what about multiple addresses? what about IPv6?

Comment: real interfaces it is ethernet type?no?
only the ipv4 family should be output, if there is more than one address then display all

Comment: actually I oversimplified there are type, kind and slave kind. a vlan interface is type ether and kind vlan. nmcli chooses to display only the kind when there's a kind and display the type when there's no kind

Comment: I am almost our what we need)

"  ip -o a show | cut -d ' ' -f 2,7  "  but the question remains with the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ip -details` gives addtional information like the interface *kind* (see later).

For real parsability, choose the JSON output and a JSON parser: [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Here's what is a one-liner but that I choose to display split over multiple lines for readability. Requires the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) utility that should be packaged in most distributions, to parse `ip -json`'s output. *jq*'s language isn't difficult to learn just by reading the link I provided.

```c
ip -details -json address show |
    jq -j '
        .[] |
              .ifname," ",
              .link_type,"/",
              .linkinfo.info_kind // "",
              if .linkinfo.info_slave_kind then
                  "/slave-",.linkinfo.info_slave_kind
              else
                  empty
              end, " ",
              ( .addr_info[] | ( .local," " ) ),
              "\n"
'
```

About interface type: actually there are two direct properties: type and kind,  and a 3rd property: slave_kind easily distinguishable from the second property only in JSON output.

- type

  Usually `loopback` (only for the loopback interface), `ether` (most interfaces are Ethernet or Ethernet-like), or `none` for Layer 3 interfaces (eg: a *wireguard* interface).
- kind

  That's what is usually thought as type. the *loopback* interface and real hardware interfaces (at least common Ethernet or Wireless) don't have a *kind* property.
- slave kind

  When an interface is enslaved, eg to a bridge or to a bond device, then this information is available in the output of the command.

you get the combined type + kind + slave kind (if you don't want all, just remove the relevant line(s)).

So for some subtleties, a combined `ether/tun` would be a tuntap device in tap mode, while a `none/tun` would be a tuntap device in tun mode (this information is also available directly in some sub field, but with the combined type+kind, no need).

To display *only* interfaces with at least one IPv4 address, the easiest is to add the `-4` option along the other options to the `ip address` command above. As this will also remove the link-layer address, interfaces without IPv4 address won't be matched by the filter and won't be displayed at all.

To remove the IPv6 output but else display *all* interfaces, don't add `-4` but instead replace:

> ```
> ( .addr_info[] | ( .local," " ) ),
> ```

with

```c
( .addr_info[] | ( if .family == "inet" then .local," " else empty end ) ),
```

Comment: this is very cool! Thanks a lot for your time, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Using `nmcli`:

```
nmcli device show |grep 'GENERAL.DEVICE:\|GENERAL.TYPE:\|IP4.ADDRESS'
```

Including IPV6:

```
nmcli device show |grep 'GENERAL.DEVICE:\|GENERAL.TYPE:\|IP4.ADDRESS\|IP6.ADDRESS'
```